# Using DocumentRoot as a variable in other sections of Apache config file

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, apache-2.4

Is there a way to use the DocumentRoot as a variable in further sections of a site's config file in Apache?

Something as below:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/myNiceRoot

<Directory $DocumentRoot/mySubDir> ... </>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [define](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define) a variable and then use that

```
Define droot /var/www/html
```

and then use it later

```
DocumentRoot ${droot}/site1
```

and so on.

Comment: A nice solution indeed. My question was assuming adding a section to the file without changing anything else. This would still do, provided I create a site file from the very beginning with such variable in it.

Comment: You can define them in different scopes - look at the docs.